# The nosql database most similar to Rethinkdb

Tags: rethinkdb

I need to do a project in rethinkdb. However, it can not work in windows. Is there a database that is seen to be most similar so that i can learn the ropes and then start my project in a unix environment. I heard this could be mongodb or couchdb. However, I would like some opinion
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different way to tackle this problem.

**Installing RethinkDB in Windows**

First, you can, in fact, get RethinkDB working on Windows. You just have to use a virtual machine. [Here is a tutorial](http://webuilddesign.com/how-to-install-windows-rethinkdb/) on how to install RethinkDB on Windows. That being said, it's not as simple to get it running on Windows as in UNIX environments.

**Similar Databases**

What NoSQL database is more similar to RethinkDB depends on what features of RethinkDB you are looking for.

If you're looking for a NoSQL JSON document store that you want to use in your server and has a similar API, [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) is probably the closes thing to RethinkDB. That being said, there are some pretty big differences between MongoDB and RethinkDB. I would take a look at an [objective look at the differences](http://rethinkdb.com/docs/comparison-tables/) and [a more opinionated look at the differences](http://rethinkdb.com/blog/mongodb-biased-comparison/).

If you're looking for something to provide RethinkDB's similar realtime features, you might take a look at [FireBase](https://www.firebase.com/). FireBase is not a NoSQL database, obviously, but it provides some of the realtime features of RethinkDB.

CouchDB might also be a good option, since it's also an open-source, NoSQL database and it also has support for [change notifications](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/notifications.html), which are a way to pull changes from a particular table (Different from [changefeed's](http://rethinkdb.com/docs/changefeeds/javascript/) push model).

**Native RethinkDB for Windows**

If you're interested in keeping track of Windows support for Windows, you should take a look at this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/1100).